# What control character is ^\ in the buffer in a file open in vim?

Tags: gvim, control-character

I found a whole bunch of green `^\` characters in the file I have open in vim...

Any idea what control character they are?

And how would I search for them in grep?

Answer (score 2):

If it is indeed a single character, it’s likely to be `<C-\>`. You can use `ga` to get the ascii, octal, etc., versions.

For `grep(1)`, most shells (my bash, at least) will let you input literals with `<C-v>` much like vim.

Answer (score 2):

File Separator, code point 28, or 0x1C, originally used to delimit data structures.

If you cannot type it with `Ctrl+\`, you can use alt codes if you have a number pad on your keyboard. Type `Alt+28` and you should get something that looks like this: ∟ You must use your number pad, the keys above the letter keys will not work. If your keyboard doesn't have a number pad, you can copy-paste the character from here: `∟`

Comment: When was it used to delimit data structures? And where?

Comment: @leand00 I got this from an ASCII table on wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators

Comment: `Alt+28` doesn't do anything except select the menus at the top when I try it, what kind of window are you typing in?

Comment: @leand00 That's probably related to Alt-Keys, they're common for disabled users and they're in a lot of programs. If you're on windows, I know that Notepad has no Alt-Key for `28`, if you're on Linux or Mac, try opening your browser and going to something like google docs (or this comment thread), because browsers rarely have Alt-Keys to prevent from interfering with webpage Access-Keys (an almost unused technology, but uninterfered with anyways) If that lets you type it in, you can probably copy-paste from there.

Comment: yes I’m on Windows

Comment: But then so is the software that generated said output.  On the other hand the output was obtained from a Cygwin terminal, so go figure...